# Select by "IN" statement with List of object's with 2 fields

Tags: java, sql, postgresql, jdbctemplate

I would like to know if there is a possibility to do a select with JDBCTemplate using `setParameter` for `List<CaseW>/Set<CaseW>` where CaseW have 2 fields with long type?

I have a table which need's select like that:

```sql
SELECT * 
FROM assertions 
WHERE (a_id, b_id) in ( (1, 15), (4, 16), (2, 13) )
```

and from my Java code I would like to do something like that:

```java
public class CaseW{
  private long a_id;
  private long b_id;

  // Constructors, getters, setters, hash codes etc.
}

public List<MyResult> getData() {
  Set<CaseW> caseW = new HashSet<CaseW>;
  caseW.add(new CaseW(1,15));
  caseW.add(new CaseW(4,16));
  caseW.add(new CaseW(1,13));

  String sql = "SELECT * " +
               "FROM assertions " +
               "WHERE (a_id, b_id) IN (:caseList) ";

  return sqlManager.createQuery(sql, MyResult.class)
                   .setParameter("caseList", caseW)
                   .getResultList();
}
```

So basically I'm wondering if it's possible to do something like that or do I need to do foreach over my Set and concat strings to prepare SQL for that "IN" statement?

I would really appreciate any suggestions how to solve this problem.

Comment: `select * from assertions where (a_id * 1000 + b_id) in (1015, 4016, 1013)`

Comment: @saka1029 yea, it will work for small numbers, but I have something like that:
`SELECT 1223372036854775807 * 1000000000000000000 + 1223372036854775807` and it throws bigint out of range